# How to use Sessions in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Like in classic PHP we use the magic variables to start and create sessions, so how to do that in Symfony?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In your controller, you can access session variables through the user object.

```
// Get a session value
$name = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('name', 'default_value');
// Set a session value
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('name', $value);
```

Comment: In your view, you can access session variables through the `$sf_user` variable, just the same way you do with `$this->getUser()` in the controller.

Comment: I don't think this will work if you don't have a user or a firewall.

Answer (score 80):

In Symfony2, the syntax is different:

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

// store an attribute for reuse during a later user request
$session->set('foo', 'bar');

// in another controller for another request
$foo = $session->get('foo');
```

You can also get session variables from Twig, without having to pass the session variable explicitly (it's in the global 'app'):

```
{{ app.session.get('foo', 'bar'); }}
```

Comment: **Symfony:** _because who really cares about the Law of Demeter anyway?_

Comment: How using sessions variables violates the Law of Demeter ?

Comment: @Videl it's not using sessions that violates LoD, its the abstraction layer from symfony.

Comment: `getRequest()` is deprecated as of Symfony 2.4. The proper way to do this now is to inject a Request into the controller and call `$request->getSession()`. http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getSession

Comment: This is literally the opposite of not caring about the law of demeter, the symfony framework is communicating with its own api