# how to store a variable value in symfony session when user is not logged in or myuser() is not set?

Tags: php, session, symfony1, session-variables

I am working on symfony 1.0 and to set a variable value into the session, we usually do is:

```
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('method', 'ajax');
```

But this will not work if no user session is set.

I want to set a variable into the session so that even after many redirects or untill I manualy clear it, it should be available to use.

This `$this->setFlash('attrib', $value);` will erase out once made an another request.

How can this be seen in symfony- I mean having a variable in session untill it is cleared manually.

Comment: `setFlash` use the same way to store value in session: `$this->setAttribute($name, $value, 'symfony/user/sfUser/flash');`

Comment: @j0k: `setFlash` keeps the values till another request is made. Bt I want to have a variable value in session even after many redirections. How is this possible in symfony. I can either use `$_SESSION['variable']="value"`. I want some specific method in sym,fony.

Comment: I don't know why, but the first code you write is ok for session: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761552/how-to-use-sessions-in-symfony

Comment: @j0k: yes But it cannot be used if NO user is logged in. my requirement is simple. I set a session in one action file and after 2 redirections, I want to use it. How it can be achieved?

Comment: There is always a session even for anonymous request, look at factory.yml under `all: storage`