# Unable to retrieve Session data in Symfony2

Tags: session, symfony, session-variables

I've written a value to the session in Symfony2 using the following code:

```
    $session = new Session();
    $session->start();
    $session->set('passport', '1');
```

And on the same page, I have used the following code to test if the value has been stored in the session, with complete success:

```
    $request = $session->get('passport');
    print_r($request);
```

However, the controller that the Session is created in then redirects the user to another controller. In this controller I have the following code:

```
public function indexAction()
{
        $request = $session->get('passport');

        if (isset($request)) {
                    do something
        } else {
            return $this->redirect("denied.html");
        }
}
```

But nothing happens. The screen just goes white, no error anything. I've replaced the `$request` variable with this code:

```
$request = '1';
```

And the code works fine. It's just when I try to get the session it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761552/how-to-use-sessions-in-symfony), and I tried the second question.

The second question added this bit of code:

```
$session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
```

I've added this, and the code now works.