# Session management in Symfony

Tags: php, session, symfony

I have two controller files in my project.
In first one, `LoginProfileController`,
and inside `LoginProfileAction` function, I write:

```
$session = new Session();
$session->start();
```

Then, I need to access the same session object in other file. Since Symfony doesn't support `$_SESSION` Variable, how can I do that?

Comment: this answer might be helpful. [How to use Sessions in Symfony?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761552/how-to-use-sessions-in-symfony)

Comment: Why you create a new session? Use the existing session in the request!

Answer (score 0):

Symfony Session is a wrapper to native php $_SESSION array. Just instantiate new $session object wherever you need it and you will have access to your session data.

Have a look at:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

BTW behind the scenes symfony uses the $_SESSION array.

Comment: This is for Symfony, Not for Symfony 2.Anyway thanks.

Comment: I don't undestand... did you setup some other session management model? Some SQL? Otherwise, I think that `@Arek S` is quite right here...

Comment: ... you can write `$session->set('foo', 'bar');` in one controller and `$session->get('foo')` in another...